# Atributes of class in numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, class, numpy, min

I have a class like:

```
class MyClass:
 def __init__( self, params):
   self.A = params[0]
   self.B = params[1]
   self.C = params[2]
```

and a numpy array built from instances of this class:

```
import numpy as np


ArrayA = np.empty((3,4),dtype = object)

for ii in range(3):
  for jj in range(4):
    ArrayA[ii,jj] = MyClass(np.random.rand(3))
```

I want to retrieve "MyClass.B" for ArrayA where "MyClass.A" is minimum, so I did:

```
WhereMin = np.where(ArrayA[:,:].A)
MinB = ArrayA[WhereMin].B
```

but that does not work. Any ideas?

**EDIT:**
When I run the above code I get the following error:

```
----> WhereMin = np.nanmin(ArrayA[:,:].A)
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'A'
```

When I would expect to get an array of indices to use in "MinB".

**Possible Solution**
I found a possible solution to my problem:

```
Min = np.nanmin([[x.A for x in XX] for XX in ArrayA])
XXX = [[x for x in XX if x.A == Min] for XX in ArrayA]
MinB = [XX for XX in XXX if XX != [] ][0][0].B
```

Might not be too elegant, but does the job. Thank you all!

Comment: What doesn't work?  How do you know it doesn't work?  Is there an error message?   If so, please show it.  Do you get unexpected output?  If so, what are you getting, and what do you expect?

Comment: @SethMMorton: Thanks for pointing that out, I updated my question with the error.

Comment: This seems like a good place to simply have a 3D array of shape `(3,4,3)`. Where the first two dimensions correspond to your original `np.empty(3,4)` array and the last dimension contains your `np.random.rand(3)`. This can be created simply as `ArrayA = np.random.rand(3,4,3)` and then the operation `np.where(ArrayA[:,:].A)` would just be `np.where(ArrayA[:,:,0]`.

Comment: @Ophion: But that would mean dropping my class all together, which I would like to avoid.

Comment: @jorgehumberto Numpy may not be the solution you want in this case. For example your proposed solution will be slower using numpy then with list of lists.

Comment: @Ophion: Then in this case it is probably best to use a list of lists. Many thanks for the advice ! :)

Answer (score 1):

The `.A` attribute belongs to each individual element of `ArrayA`, not to the array as a whole.  So, `ArrayA[0,0].A` is valid, because `ArrayA[0,0]` points to an instance of `MyClass`, but `ArrayA[:,:]` returns a copy of the original `ndarray`.

I would consider reorganizing your data so that you keep everything you want in the `.A` attribute in a single numpy array, and everything in `.B` in a single numpy array, etc. That would have two advantages, 1) you would be able to use `where`, and 2) your numpy arrays would be of `dtype=float` (you lose the advantage of `numpy` if you have to use `dtype=object`).

Comment: I see your point, but unfortunately I don't think that would work for me. I use the numpy array to store an instance of the object for a grid of values. Maybe instead I should use a different approach, like trying with a list of lists?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a structured numpy array.  Pass dtype a list of tuples of field name and data type. You can then access the complete array of a given field by indexing the array by the field name. To rework your example:

```
ArrayA = np.zeros((3,4),dtype=[('A','<f4'),('B','<f4'),('C','<f4')])

for ii in range(3):
  for jj in range(4):
    ArrayA[ii,jj] = np.random.rand(3)

minA = ArrayA['A'].min()
WhereMin = np.where(a['A'] == minA)
MinB = ArrayA[WhereMin]['B']
```

Comment: That is a solution, but it would mean dropping my class all together. Problem is the "real" class I use is more complex and is used on other parts of the code, So I would like to avoid that. Thanks anyway!:)

Comment: Depending on how often you want to perform array operations on instances of your class, you can keep the relevant fields stored in a numpy structured array, and have the class instance keep an index into the array